# VS 2010 Team Foundation Server Issue with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

I'm trying to setup VS 2010 Team Foundation project in TFS 2010.  When I go to create the sharepoint site for the project, it errors saying I don't have permissions... what permissions do I need to grant, and is it a windows permission or within the sharepoint application?  I don't have a full blown sharepoint instance, but am using 3.0 services.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/249becf3-7e8e-4a74-bab3-58e421abbd4a

HTH.